# lines can be neither intersecting nor parallel. Why is that?

Tags: geometry

There are two chords on the circle, $CD$ and $EF$. $CD$ is the diameter. $CD$ is not parallel to $EF$. When the radius of this circle tends to infinity, $CD$ and $EF$ tend to infinity, and $CD$ and $EF$ are straight lines (because their length tends to infinity). So lines can be neither intersecting nor parallel. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: The lines $CD$ and $EF$ indisputably intersect.

Comment: For any finite value of the radius the lines will intersect at a finite distance from the circle center. The fact that the distance tends to infinity does not matter.

Comment: In the first place, CD and EF only exist on this circle. If you increase the radius, you have to specify what the corresponding segments on the larger circle are -- which you haven't done. So the question is meaningless without that.

Comment: @MPW Just add 0's to the axis scales to increase the circle radius. The figure remains similar to what's shown here regardless of scale.

Answer (score 3):

Before you "reach infinity", they are never lines. They are only ever *line segments*. And there is nothing in Euclidean plane geometry that says non-parallel segments must intersect.

After you have passed to infinity, they will be lines, and at this stage they *will* either be parallel, or they will intersect.

There is no contradiction here. Some things change when you go from finite, bounded to infinite, unbounded, and some things are kept unchanged. Picking and choosing what gets kept and what gets changed so that you reach a seeming contradiction is not how it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they intersect as the length goes to infinity? One could write an expression for the distance between points C and E (the line segments' closest points), and see that the distance between the line segments also goes to infinity as the circle's radius goes to infinity. I can't quite reconcile that with the notion that the lines intersect, since the line segments only become more distant as the circle gets bigger. Where do the lines intersect, if C and E are as close as they get, which are always separated by a nonzero distance?

Comment: @NuclearWang As we don't really know how the points (and thus the chords) change with the increasing diameter, we can't really say anything definitive at all. All I can say with what is given here is that the alleged contradiction never occurrs.

Comment: I'm assuming the shape remains similar to the one shown as it gets blown up. You can just add 0's to the axis scales to make the circle larger and larger. It seems pretty straightforward to me to write a definitive equation that describes the distance between C and E, depending only on r. We clearly have one for the distance between C and D - it's 2r.

Comment: @NuclearWang Well, in that case we can't even pass to infinity in any sensible manner; $EF$ wouldn't go to anything, it would just disappear off into infinity.

Comment: @NuclearWang I think the same as you.

Comment: @Arthur Unclear why you can't take a limit of the situation I described. The distance between E and F goes to infinity, which is kind of the point - as the circle becomes infinitely large, line segment EF becomes a line. I'm not sure what the case you're referring to is where we *can* pass to infinity in a sensible manner.

Comment: @NuclearWang : In the limit, the circle and the nonhorizontal figure vanish. You are left only with the x-axis. There is no limiting point in the plane of either the circle or the other line.

Comment: @MPW According to your logic, if there is an observer standing on the $EF$ line to observe the x-axis, will the x-axis disappear when the radius of the circle tends to be infinite?

Comment: @u3770435 : No, the observer will disappear. He is on an object that tends to infinity (swallowed by the balck hole of Cygnus X-1, I suppose).

Comment: @MPW To the observer on EF, the x-axis tends to infinity.

Comment: @u3770435 : That changes the problem and its assumptions completely. The problem is implicitly scaling at the origin. The results are completely dependent on the center of scaling. At any of C, D, E, or F, the circle becomes a line in the limit and does not vanish. Let’s stick with the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, $CD$ and $EF$ are line segments, not straight lines.  It is possible, depending on how you take the limit, that their limits are straight lines.  In that case those limiting straight lines are either parallel or intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the stretching is standard euclidean scaling from the center $(0,0)$ by a factor $t\in[1,\infty[\>$. If we do this right in your figure then the line $C_t\vee D_t=C\vee D$ for all $t\geq1$, hence  remains the $x$-axis in the limit. But the line $E\vee F$ has no limiting line in the plane: All points $(u,v)$  of the initial line $E_1\vee F_1$ wander to infinity under our continuous stretching. Note that the line $E_1\vee F_1$ has a positive distance $\rho_1>0$ from $(0,0)$ at the start, and the distance of $E_t\vee F_t$ from $(0,0)$ will be $\rho_t=t\rho\to\infty$ when $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Lines in a plane must intersect or be parallel to one another. If neither are true, I would argue that we are not actually talking about lines. Suppose we change the figure to put point E on the origin, and fix it there. We can then enlarge the circle, moving toward the limit of infinite radius, while keeping E fixed on the origin. In this case, in the limit of infinite radius, CD becomes a line, but EF becomes a ray, not a line (because E is a fixed, immovable point). CD and EF are not parallel and do not intersect, even though they both have infinite length, because they are not both lines.

Under this construction, we remove the paradox entirely - we have a circle whose radius approaches infinity, and two chords whose length approach infinity. The chords are neither parallel nor intersecting, but because they are not both lines, we have no contradiction.

Admittedly, I'm not entirely sure how to reconcile this with the case of the center at the origin, in which case both chords do have infinite length and no fixed endpoint. I wonder if those conditions are indeed sufficient to define a line.

Answer (score -2):

On larger circles, since $IL$ is parallel to $EF$, $EF$ will not be parallel to $CD$ when the radius of the circle tends to be infinite.

[image]

I use large and small circles to explain that they are still not parallel as the radius of the circle tends to infinity.

Comment: In this case the line segments $EF$, $IJ$, ... do not have a straight line as limit.

Comment: The fact that EF and CD are not parallel isn't in dispute, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @NuclearWang  I use large and small circles to explain that they are still not parallel as the radius of the circle tends to infinity.

Comment: @RobertIsrae  But when the radius of a circle tends to infinity, they are not line segments.

Comment: Nor are they lines.  They go off to infinity as the radius tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael When R is ♾, they are also ♾.  So they are straight lines.